# Server failed to save file when upload file in IE 11 using formData

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, form-data

The following code works well in Chrome, Firefox, Safari. But our service can't save file successfully in IE 11.

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', sampleFile)

ajax({
    url: uploadURL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  })
```

How to resolve this issue?

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', sampleFile, sampleFile.name)

ajax({
    url: uploadURL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  })
```

I guess that IE uses the real file path name as file name but other browsers only use file name without file path. So we need to use the third optional parameter to pass a filename.

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: 500. Can't save file xxxx(my local file path name).

Comment: That means the error was on the server, check the server's logs to see what the problem was.

Comment: if you are recieving file on server side / controller then its could be anything on server, may be you don't have rights  or filesize issue, etc

Comment: From the error code, perhaps the issue is related to the server side service, try to set break point in the server side service, then, step by step to debug your code and check whether you could get the upload file. Besides, you could also use F12 developer tools to check the ajax request, and compare the request difference between IE browser and Chrome browser.

Comment: If still not solved the problem, please post more related code about the service method, so that we could reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The issue has been resolved. I can't get the service code. So I can't find the root cause. According to the error message, the file name contains a slash-separated list of directory names in IE 11. Slash is a special character. I think it causes this issue.